# Consultas array MongoDB

Tags: array, mongodb

antes de escribir la consulta la he buscado por aquí, pero no la he encontrado. Si ya existe, me disculpo de antemano.

Veréis, tengo una colección que dentro tiene un array llamado "grades" que tiene 5 colecciones con 3 grupos de datos. En este caso lo que me interesa mostrar es uno de esos datos llamado "score".

Puedo acceder por ejemplo a la primera de esas colecciones indicando el índice, un punto y el dato:

```
            db.restaurantes.find({},{"grades.0.score": 1})
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿Hay alguna forma de sacar los datos "score" accediendo a los 5 índices a la vez?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Me suena a algo que podrías lograr una vez que obtengas la información con algún `.map()` / `.reduce()` pero seguramente es algo que podrías lograr directamente con mongodb. Tal vez te sirva leer sobre el operador de agregación [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/).

Comment: Algo que también ayudaría a resolver el problema, es que incluyas tu estructura de datos a modo de un [mcve] ya que podría resultar difícil de imaginar cómo es tu estructura, o podría prestarse a malas interpretaciones.

Comment: Podrías mostrar un ejemplo de documento tal como está en DB y un ejemplo de la salida que deseas, además de la salida actual?